# Double quotes within string like triple double quote in Python

Tags: java

Within Python I can use:

```
test = """My "cute" string"""
```

Where the double quotes get escaped. Is there a way that I can emulate this within Java without using escape slashes?

Comment: `test = "\"My \"cute\" string\"";`
This can be done with escape slashes.

Comment: He said without escape characters

Comment: I don't see how it will be easier to use the approach mentioned below answers  rather than escaping it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triple quotes in Java like Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356801/triple-quotes-in-java-like-scala)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no sensible way of doing that in Java. Judging from the other answers, I'd say that escaping the quotes is the path of least pain.

It is possible in Groovy (which also runs on the Java VM), though, using either single quotes:

```
`'some "String"'`
```

or the so-called here documents:

```
""" Everything here can be "quoted"
/"""
```

But Java has no such mechanism.

Comment: Well if we are abandoning Java then why not go the whole way and use Jython? I'm pretty sure that's as close to Python style string literals as you can possibly get on the JVM.

Comment: Good point, but I don't have any experience with Python, so I didn't think of that

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a reason not to escape `"`, but.. you can do:

```
System.out.println((char)34+"Some Text"+(char)34); //See ASCII table for more information
```

Output >> "Some Text"

Comment: Agreed. Downvoter, this is so far the only answer to adhere to the "without using escape slashes" requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need an escape, you should use string concatenation such as:

```
test = '"' + "My " + '"' + "cute" + '"' + " string" + '"';
```

Or using `StringBuffer` to append `"` character if you want.

Another way to do that is using `String.format`:

```
test = String.format("%1$sMy %1$scute%1$s string%1$s", '"');
```

Which replaces `%1$s` by your give "quote" later.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd: Of course, I do not recommend to write a code like that. But I think that is a good way to have `"` character without escape.

Comment: @TuTran, all pther approach instead of using `\\` will be error prone. Try using below answer's approach with OP's sample and the outcome complexity is same

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with Java 15, Java now supports triple-quotes! See [JEP 355](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355) for details. In Java 13/14, this was available as a preview.

Comment: note that it was a Preview feature in 13; but official by 15:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839267/1357094

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `\u0022`.

```
String str= "\u0022 MyString \u0022";
```

But this is quite similar to escaping `"` by `\`

Comment: Seems this still uses an escape slash