# Triple quotes in Java like Scala

Tags: java, scala, java-text-blocks

In Scala you can do something like this:

```
val expr = """ This is a "string" with "quotes" in it! """
```

Is there something like this in Java? I abhor using `"\""` to represent strings with quotes in them. Especially when composing key/value pairs in JSON. Disgusting!

Comment: take a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324715/double-quotes-within-string-like-triple-double-quote-in-python

Comment: I don't think there's an other way in Java. You know every language is different!

Comment: It might be easier to the JSON in a separate file, and read from it.

Comment: You should use a JSON library to compose your JSON, rather than string concatenation.

Comment: @DavidConrad - I agree, but if you're just trying to whip up something simple, triple quotes out of the box as a language feature would be super nifty

Comment: Although this mostly duplicates [prior Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20324715/1357094), this one has since received better [Java 15] Answers for `Text Blocks`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Note: This answer was written prior to Java 15, which [introduced the triple-quote text block feature](https://www.baeldung.com/java-text-blocks).  Please see [@epox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28356801/triple-quotes-in-java-like-scala/59839267#59839267) for how to use this feature.*

---

There is no good alternative to using `\"` to include double-quotes in your string literal.

There are bad alternatives:

- Use `\u0022`, the Unicode escape for a double-quote character.  The compiler treats a Unicode escape as if that character was typed.  It's treated as a double-quote character in the *source code*, ending/beginning a `String` literal, so this does NOT work.
- Concatenate the character `'"'`, e.g. `"This is a " + '"' + "string"`.  This will work, but it seems to be even uglier and less readable than just using `\"`.
- Concatenate the `char` 34 to represent the double-quote character, e.g. `"This is a " + (char) 34 + "string"`.  This will work, but it's even less obvious that you're attempting to place a double-quote character in your string.
- Copy and paste Word's "smart quotes", e.g. `"This is a “string” with “quotes” in it!"`.  These aren't the same characters (Unicode U+201C and U+201D); they have different appearances, but they'll work.

I suppose to hide the "disgusting"-ness, you could hide it behind a constant.

```
public static final String DOUBLE_QUOTE = "\"";
```

Then you could use:

```
String expr = " This is a " + DOUBLE_QUOTE + "string" + DOUBLE_QUOTE + ...;
```

It's more readable than other options, but it's still not very readable, and it's still ugly.

There is no `"""` mechanism in Java, so using the escape `\"`, is the best option.  It's the most readable, and it's the least ugly.

Comment: Using Groovy is might also be an option.

Comment: Why would you use `DOUBLE_QUOTE` or `(char)34` instead of `'"'` (a single-quoted double-quote char)? The best option is still `\"`, but I think it's strange you left out `'"'`.

Comment: I suppose, for completeness, you could mention using some unrelated character that you know will not be in the data, say '#', and then doing a replace afterwards to turn them into quotes. But that seems very hack-y.

Comment: [Java 13/15+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839267/1357094) has better `Text Blocks` alternative.

Answer (score 25):

### Since Java 15

or since Java 13 **preview feature**. REF: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/355

It doesn't work precisely in Scala way. The opening triple quotes **must** be followed by a new line.

```
var expr = """
           This is a 1-line "string" with "quotes" and no leading spaces in it! """;
```

The position of the closing triple quotes matters. It defines the indent size. For example, for having 2 spaces indent, you position your closing `"""` as follows:

```
String sql = """
               SELECT   emp_id, last_name
               FROM     postgres.employee
               WHERE    city = 'INDIANAPOLIS'
               ORDER BY emp_id, last_name;
             """;
```

this would result in 4 lines of text:

```
  SELECT   emp_id, last_name
  FROM     postgres.employee
  WHERE    city = 'INDIANAPOLIS'
  ORDER BY emp_id, last_name;
```

---

### Escaping:

Tripple quotes escaping is intuitive:

```
String txt = """
    A text block with three quotes \""" inside.""";
```

`\` (backslash) is still a special symbol. You have to escape it by doubling `\\`:

```
String txt = """
    A text block with a single blackslash \\ in it.""";
```

---

### Trailing spaces

Java compiler **ignores** any ending spaces.

WORKAROUND: add `\s` to the end of the line. ([Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-text-blocks#escaping-spaces))

---

### Windows `\r\n` line terminators

No matter if you compile in MacOs or Windows, the string constant will always use `\n` and only `\n`

WORKAROUND: add `\r` to the end of the line. ([Baeldung example](https://www.baeldung.com/java-text-blocks#escaping-line-terminators))

---

### Concatenating 2 lines

Since Java 14 preview, you may continue the same line below, if the previous one ended with a single backslash:

```
 var oneLine = """
               This is one \
                 line of text!""";
```

Result:

```
This is one   line of text!
```

## Enjoy ;)

You can play with the output right away in an online Java 17+ compiler: https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler/

---

**NOTE:** If using in Java 13(14), the feature was preview, there. So you could not use it in Java 13(14), unless you set the `--enable-preview TextBlock` key.

Answer (score 4):

Found this question while doing the same thing: composing small literal JSON strings for quick testing. One alternative that didn't come up is to use double single-quotes and replace them with double quotes, something like:

```
String json = "{ ''label'' : ''set range'', ''min'' : 0, ''max'' : 100}".replace("''", "\"")
```

Obviously this doesn't work if there's a regular double single quote, but chances of that should be slim. It's not a great solution, but looks better than lots of backslashes, imo. As an intermediate step to putting the json in a separate file, this is probably not too bad.

Comment: Unstable. You would unpredictably break original values in some cases: {"msg": "Expected: not empty string. Was: arg=' ' ."}.

Comment: As I said, "Obviously this doesn't work if there's a regular double single quote". This is just a quick stopgap for debugging, shouldn't be used in production code. But I thought that was obvous from the answer...

Comment: Elegant hack! I'd be even cruder*, and use single-quotes, a-la JavaScript. *Crude-but-effective.

Comment: @Markhu, yes, this would work with basically any non-double-quote character (or character sequence). I simply picked `''` because it's similar to double-quote and unlikely to appear in the tokens I wanted to add.

Answer (score 2):

The feature that you want is called `Text Blocks` and delivered in Java 15, [JEP378](https://openjdk.org/jeps/378).

#### History

> Text blocks were proposed by JEP 355 in early 2019 as a follow-on to
> explorations begun in JEP 326 (Raw String Literals), which was
> initially targeted to JDK 12 but eventually withdrawn and did not
> appear in that release. JEP 355 was targeted to JDK 13 in June 2019 as
> a preview feature. Feedback on JDK 13 suggested that text blocks
> should be previewed again in JDK 14, with the addition of two new
> escape sequences. Consequently, JEP 368 was targeted to JDK 14 in
> November 2019 as a preview feature. Feedback on JDK 14 suggested that
> text blocks were ready to become final and permanent in JDK 15 with no
> further changes.

#### Usage

```
String query = """
               SELECT "EMP_ID", "LAST_NAME" FROM "EMPLOYEE_TB"
               WHERE "CITY" = 'INDIANAPOLIS'
               ORDER BY "EMP_ID", "LAST_NAME";
               """;
```

Answer (score 1):

The feature of `"Raw String Literals"` was meant to be in **Java 12**, but was [withdrawn](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk-dev/2018-December/002402.html) due to some criticism, because they planned to use variable number of backquotes (`).

So it is in **Java 13** finally, as `"Text Block"` feature, but in **preview** only. It is using `"""` operator like in Scala.

You can read more on Java 13 features [here](https://www.journaldev.com/33204/java-13-features#1-text-blocks-8211-jep-355).

Answer (score 0):

The triple quote feature is available since **Java 14**. For more details, see for instance, https://howtodoinjava.com/java14/java-text-blocks/