# How to insert an Integer variable in a String variable in Java

Tags: java

I need to insert an Integer variable (myLonString) in a String variable (myBufferSendTrama) in Java

```
Integer myLonString;
String valoOfLongOfString = Integer.toString(lonString);
myBufferSendTrama = "{\"f\":\"valoOfLongOfString\"}";     //ERROR
```

If the integer variable equals 20, it should look like this:

```
myBufferSendTrama = "{\"f\":\"20\"}";
```

Comment: Try this?
`myBufferSendTrama = "{\"f\":\"" + valoOfLongOfString + "\"}";`

Comment: In this case, maybe it's better to use a Json library?

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate both strings, like:

```
String s1 = "jon";
String s2 = " doe";

String s3 = s1 + s2; // "jon doe"
```

Check out [this](https://www.educba.com/java-string-concatenation/) page for more information

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String.format("{\"f\":\"%s\"}", valoOfLongOfString)`.

More information can be found in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your version of Java, you can make use of `"""` [String literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59839267/12764490) and `String.format()` to achieve the effect fairly cleanly.

**Example:**

```
int value = 20;
String out = String.format("""
    Value is "%d".
    """, value);
System.out.println(out);
```

**Output**

```
Value is "20".
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert the Integer to a String, just do:

```
Integer myLonString;
myBufferSendTrama = String.format("{\"f\":\"%d\"}",(int) myLonString);
```